# How to get content of multiple azure storage blobs in parallel in scala

Tags: scala, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-storage-account

I am working on a scala code which needs to retrieve contents of multiple azure storage blobs to start the logic execution. Downloading the contents sequentially is time taking. Do storage blob APIs offer a bulk download option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do storage blob APIs offer a bulk download option?

Unfortunately there's no batch download capability available in Azure Blob Storage. You will need to download each blob individually. What you could do is download blobs in parallel to speed things up.